# Is it possible to diff two perl arrays using awk?

Tags: arrays, perl, awk

I usually do diff between two files with awk in perl as shown below.

```
my @awkoutput = system("awk 'NR == FNR { A[\$0]=1; next } !A[\$0]' file1.txt file2.txt");
```

But, is it possible to do a similar diff between two perl arrays ?

I don't think its possible. We may have to move all perl array elements to files and do it. All I'm trying to find is do diff without creating the files.

Comment: It's insane to call awk from perl like that

Comment: So just loop over both arrays and print the diffs!?

Comment: Yes. I'm limited to awk in perl. I don't have modules installed like `List::Compare`, `Text::Diff` etc. The file contents look alike.

Comment: Note that your `awk` script is asymmetric. It reports on lines found in file 2 that are not present in file 1; it does not report on lines found in file 1 that are not present in file 2.  As long as that's what you want, it's fine.  (It's a weird way of doing it, but it 'works'.)

Comment: @sudo_O: we are already looping arrays and printing the diffs but its taking us insane 40 mins while awk does that in a minute. (files are really huge 100 MB for example)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Yes, that is what I want. :)

Comment: @FlyingFrog: Sorry, I shouldn't have said 100 MB. I just meant the amount of time its taking to get the output

Comment: @nlrreddy then I would bet you are doing something wrong! If you are worried about size then why do you have perl arrays or 100MB then build `awk` array of the same size!? Either process your whole input with `perl` **or** with `awk`.

Comment: Interesting that no one suggested the smart-match operator `~~`.

Comment: @cdarke Perhaps because as of 5.18 [smartmatch is experimental](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.18.0/pod/perldelta.pod#The_smartmatch_family_of_features_are_now_experimental): `It is clear that smartmatch is almost certainly either going to change or go away in the future. Relying on its current behavior is not recommended.`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given:

```
my @array1 = ( "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl" );
my @array2 = ( "xyz", "abc", "jkl", "mnp" );
```

which are populated with the data that would otherwise be written to `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, then you can transliterate your `awk` into Perl:

```
{
    my %file1;
    foreach (@array1) { $file1{$_} = 1; }
    foreach (@array2) { print $_ unless $file1{$_}; }
}
```

The braces ensure that `%file1` only lasts for that block of code.  For the given arrays, that code outputs:

```
xyz
mnp
```

Even if the array is 100 MiB of data, it isn't likely to be any slower than writing two files and invoking `awk` on them.

#### Timing

What sort of machine are you using that it takes a minute to process the data?  Here's a trivial revision of the script above. I generated two files with random numbers in otherwise similar lines, with the ranges of the random numbers overlapping.

```
$ random -F "The random line contains %d to make it different sometimes" -n 1000000 1 999999 > file1.txt
$ random -F "The random line contains %d to make it different sometimes" -n 1000000 500000 1499999 > file2.txt
$ time perl x3.pl > file3.txt

real    0m2.983s
user    0m2.642s
sys     0m0.332s
$ wc -l file?.txt
 1000000 file1.txt
 1000000 file2.txt
  683637 file3.txt
 2683637 total
$ ls -l file?.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  eng  62888452 Oct 15 08:14 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  eng  63500365 Oct 15 08:15 file2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 jleffler  eng  43569496 Oct 15 08:17 file3.txt
$ time awk 'NR == FNR { A[$0]=1; next } !A[$0]' file1.txt file2.txt > file4.txt

real    0m3.853s
user    0m3.670s
sys     0m0.174s
$ cmp file[34].txt
$
```

This was run on a MacBook Pro with 16 GiB memory and SSD, but even so, Perl took less than 3 seconds to read the two 60+ MiB files and produce the differences, and for comparison, `awk` took under 4 seconds.

#### Script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $f1, '<', 'file1.txt' or die;
my @array1 = <$f1>;
open my $f2, '<', 'file2.txt' or die;
my @array2 = <$f2>;

{
my %file1;
foreach (@array1) { $file1{$_} = 1; }
foreach (@array2) { print "$_" unless $file1{$_}; }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for. No more awk in my perl script. :)

Thank you !

Comment: 1 min is just an exaggerated amount of time that I mentioned. accurately it would probably take around 10 sec I believe. I run these on a solaris zone. thanks again !

Comment: Fair enough, but here on SO we value accuracy, so both the durations and the ratios matter. Avoid exaggeration; it leads to people being puzzled unnecessarily. You don't have to be precise to the millisecond or anything silly, but you should be in the right ball-park. Solaris zones aren't necessarily as fast as single-user laptops. It's also quite conceivable that the data I wrote was all in main memory, not fully backed up to SSD, so I may have got blazingly fast times because of cache effects.  But that is also why I identified where I ran my tests; platform matters.